# How to convert epoch time to Human readable in Teradata

Tags: teradata, epoch

In my Teradata table, I have the epoch timestamps under the column `dhTimestamp`

```
dhTimestamp  
1435308067705  
1434965874565  
1434763800794  
1434775876034  
1434765207057
```

How can I convert the epoch timestamp to Human Date/Time format on Teradata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a SQL UDF for standard unixtime:

```
/**********
Converting Unix/POSIX time to a Timestamp 

Unix time: Number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC not counting leap seconds (currently 24 in 2011)

Also working for negative numbers.
The maximum range of Timestamps is based on the range of INTEGERs:
1901-12-13 20:45:52 (-2147483648) to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 (2147483647)

Can be changed to use BIGINT instead of INTEGER

20101211 initial version - Dieter Noeth
**********/

REPLACE FUNCTION Epoch2Timestamp (UnixTime INT)
RETURNS TimeStamp(0)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (UnixTime / 86400) AS TIMESTAMP(0))
+ ((UnixTime MOD 86400) * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND)
;

SELECT
   Epoch2Timestamp(-2147483648)
  ,Epoch2Timestamp(0)
  ,Epoch2Timestamp(2147483647)
;
```

But your values seem to include milliseconds, this needs a modified calculation:

```
CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (UnixTime / 86400000) AS TIMESTAMP(3))
+ ((UnixTime / 1000.000 MOD 86400) * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND)
```

### Edit 2016-07-01:

There was an issue with dayight saving time (see [this thread](http://forums.teradata.com/forum/general/convert-13-digit-epoch-time-to-date#comment-148179) on Teradata's on DevEx), this should fix it:

```
-- Unix time to Timestamp WITH TIME ZONE (+00:00)
REPLACE FUNCTION UnixTime_to_TimeStamp_TZ (UnixTime INT)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN
  ((CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (UnixTime / 86400) AS TIMESTAMP(0) AT 0)) AT 0)
+ ((UnixTime MOD 86400) * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND);

-- Unixtime to Timestamp, implicit TIME ZONE of the local session
REPLACE FUNCTION UnixTime_to_TimeStamp (UnixTime INT)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP(0)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN
  CAST(((CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (UnixTime / 86400) AS TIMESTAMP(0) AT 0)) AT 0)
     + ((UnixTime MOD 86400) * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND) AS TIMESTAMP(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most simplied way to convert EPOCH TO TERADATA LOCAL.

```
SELECT
   dhTimestamp as unix_epoc_time   , 

   to_timestamp(unix_epoc_time) utc,   

   cast(cast(utc as char(19))||'+00:00' as timestamp(0) with time zone) AT LOCAL
```

1. If you have epoch with more than 10 digit , then chop the numbers after 10th digit, It will just work fine.
2. remember , Unix time is in UTC.
3. your system will treat this `utc` as local. So, let us make it understand that it is UTC by adding `'+00:00'` and then convert it to your LOCAL using `AT LOCAL` OR using either of these "America Central" , "America Eastern" , "America Mountain" etc..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert epoch column to timestamp using below query..

`SELECT CAST((date '1970-01-01' + CAST(epochtimecolumn/1000 AS INTEGER)/86400) AS TIMESTAMP(6)) +  (CAST(epochtimecolumn/1000 AS INTEGER) MOD 86400) * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND + (epcho_time_column_with_milliseconds MOD 1000) * INTERVAL '00:00:00.001' HOUR TO SECOND from table_name`

Just replace **epochtimecolumn** with your column in the above query to run it in teradata.

Hope it helps!!